# Sitecore admin account permission related issue

Tags: sitecore

In Sitecore admin portal I created an user with following roles

[image]

When I open a Sitecore item and try to edit using Content Editor it first asks me to lock the item before making any edits.
When I select "Lock and Edit" option then it says

```
If you publish now, the selected version will not be visible on the Web site because it has been replaced by an older version.
```

When I try to do the same thing using a Sitecore administrator account it doesn't ask me to lock it and the editing works fine. Is there a problem with Sitecore roles for this user?

There is something happening other than this, when I select Lock and Edit option it will create a new version instead of editing the same version. For administrator users that doesn't happen. So I think creating a new version is the main reason for this.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, this is the expected behavior. Only *real* administrators (where "User is administrator" is checked in the General tab on your screenshot) are able to bypass these security mechanisms.

Comment: Do you have any idea why currently edited version is replaced by an older version and it would not be visible.

Comment: I guess there is a workflow configured for your item and the new version has not been approved so far.

Answer (score 2):

Using Reflector I checked where `scEditorWarningTitle` (scEditorWarningTitle being the class of the title of the warning message) is being used. I found out that that's in the Sitecore.Client.dll, specifically in `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentMnaager.Editor.RenderWarning`. That namespace also has a `GetWarnings` method, which ciks off the `getContentEditorWarnings` pipeline:

```
using (new LongRunningOperationWatcher(Settings.Profiling.RenderFieldThreshold, "GetContentEditorWarningsArgs pipeline", new string[0]))
{
    CorePipeline.Run("getContentEditorWarnings", args);
}
```

Looking at that pipeline, we can see that it does the following (by default, at least in Sitecore 6.5 update 5 - this might be different in other versions of Sitecore):

```
<getContentEditorWarnings>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.ItemNotFound, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.CanReadLanguage, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.HasNoVersions, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.CanWrite, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.CanWriteWorkflow, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.CanWriteLanguage, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.IsReadOnly, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.IsLocked, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.HasNoFields, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.NeverPublish, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.ItemPublishingRestricted, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.VersionPublishingRestricted, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.ShowingInputBoxes, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.FeedIsEmpty, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.RunRules, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.Notifications, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
</getContentEditorWarnings>
```

Again in Sitecore 6.5 update 5 the only `VersionPublishingRestricted` warnings I see are:

> If you publish now, the selected version will not be visible on the
>   Web site because it is not in the final workflow step
>   If you publish now, the selected version will not be visible on the
>   Web site because today does not fall within its valid date range
>  If
>   you publish now, the selected version will not be visible on the Web
>   site because it has been replaced by a newer version 
> If you publish
>   now, the selected version will not be visible on the Web site

With the possibility of a description of either

> Version X will be published instead

or

> No other version will be published

All other processors I checked that are in the pipeline have no mention of being replaced by an older version either. 
If the older isn't a typo, it'd be worth either looking into the `getContentEditorWarnings` pipeline or check your rules (which are located in `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Content Editor Warnings/Rules`)

**Edit**
Right, as @horseman says, in Sitecore 6.6 this is in the `VersionPublishingRestrictions`:

```
 if ((validVersion != null) && (item.Version.Number < validVersion.Version.Number))
 {
     warning.Title = Translate.Text("If you publish now, the selected version will not be visible on the Web site because it has been replaced by a newer version.");
 }
 else if ((validVersion != null) && (item.Version.Number > validVersion.Version.Number))
 {
     warning.Title = Translate.Text("If you publish now, the selected version will not be visible on the Web site because it has been replaced by an older version.");
 }
 else if (IsInWorkflow(item))
 {
     warning.Title = Translate.Text("If you publish now, the selected version will not be visible on the Web site because it is not in the final workflow step.");
 }
 else if ((item.Publishing.ValidFrom > now) || (item.Publishing.ValidTo <= now))
 {
     warning.Title = Translate.Text("If you publish now, the selected version will not be visible on the Web site because today does not fall within its valid date range.");
 }
 else
 {
     warning.Title = Translate.Text("If you publish now, the selected version will not be visible on the Web site.");
 }
```

So, if there's a valid version, and the valid version number is smaller than the currently selected item's version number you'll get the message:

`If you publish now, the selected version will not be visible on the Web site because it has been replaced by an older version.`